# How to select using List<String> as input at Repository?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, orm

My input List : `["keyA", "keyB", "keyC"]`

I hope to query work like this :
`WHERE key = keyA OR key = keyB OR key = keyC`

And I tried to generate method at my repository like this.

```java
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

     // here... like this:
     // List<MyEntity> findByKey(List<String> myList);
}
```

So, I know the above method is wrong. 
How do I make it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to suffix your column you search by `IN`:

```
 List<MyEntity> findByKeyIn(List<String> myList);
```